# Google Sheets ImportXML not working, but it should?

Tags: html, google-sheets, xpath

The relevant html:
(URL: https://www.lego.com/sv-se/service/buildinginstructions/75060)

```
<div class="c-card__inner">
  <div
    class="c-card__img o-inline-img o-inline-img--contain o-inline-img--inset o-ratio o-ratio--four-three o-ratio--fit-vert"
    data-cy="bi-product-img"
    style="background-image: url("https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.img.pri/75060_prod.jpg");"
  ></div>
</div>
```

But both the following give me `Imported Xml content cannot be parsed.`

`=IMPORTXML(\<URL\>,"//div\[@class='c-card__inner')\]\[1\]/div\[1\]/@style\[1\]")`

`=IMPORTXML(\<URL\>,"//div\[@class='c-card__inner')\]/div/@style")`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can I ask you for detailed information about the value you want to retrieve?

Comment: I want to get the url from the background-image propery, but even just getting the whole line is fine; I'd just use some regexextract to get the specific bit.
Problem is I can't get anything to be returned.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your URL, unfortunately, it seems that your expected value is prepared with Javascript. In this case, IMPORTXML cannot be used. And also, Google Apps Script cannot be used. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: oh interesting. How did you see that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `How did you see that?`, as a simple method, when IMPORTDATA is used, the HTML is retrieved. When the expected value is not included in it, I think that it might be difficult to directly retrieve the value with IMPORTXML.

Comment: @sarckasm It may not be important.. but the html you shared has surely a problem in the style attribute where you didn't escape the double quote

Comment: @DiegoD oh I noticed that terrible code, but unfortunately it's not mine to edit, it's LEGO's website :)

Comment: @sarckasm I think this `style="background-image: url(&quot;https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.img.pri/75060_prod.jpg&quot;);"` is the raw code in the lego website. Or just use single quotes/double quotes so that they don't collide